# Youtube integration with iOS app - unexpected error

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube-api

I'm following this example https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/source/browse/#svn/trunk/Examples/YouTubeSample to integrate YouTube SDK into my iOS app.
Here are some jobs I have done:
 - Add the GTL.project into my project and set the source path for Header Search Path.
 - Link the GTLTouchStaticLib to Link Binary with Libraries of my project.
 - Add GTLYouTube_Sources.m into my project.
 - Copy some codes from YouTubeSample, here is the code snippet:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

#import "GTLYouTube.h"

#import "GTLUtilities.h"
#import "GTMHTTPUploadFetcher.h"
#import "GTMHTTPFetcherLogging.h"
#import "GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.h"
.
.
- (IBAction)Login:(id)sender {

    GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *viewController;
    viewController = [[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch alloc] initWithScope:kGTLAuthScopeYouTube
                                                                 clientID:kMyClientID
                                                             clientSecret:kMyClientSecret
                                                         keychainItemName:kKeychainItemName
                                                                 delegate:self
                                                         finishedSelector:@selector(viewController:finishedWithAuth:error:)];

    [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
}

- (void)viewController:(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *)viewController
      finishedWithAuth:(GTMOAuth2Authentication *)auth
                 error:(NSError *)error {
    if (error == nil) {
        self.youTubeService.authorizer = auth;
//        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
        [self fetchMyChannelList];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Auth failed: %@", error);
    }
}

- (void)fetchMyChannelList {
    NSLog(@"fetchMyChannelList");
    _myPlaylists = nil;
    _channelListFetchError = nil;

    GTLServiceYouTube *service = self.youTubeService;

    GTLQueryYouTube *query = [GTLQueryYouTube queryForChannelsListWithPart:@"contentDetails"];

    query.mine = YES;

    // maxResults specifies the number of results per page.  Since we earlier
    // specified shouldFetchNextPages=YES, all results should be fetched,
    // though specifying a larger maxResults will reduce the number of fetches
    // needed to retrieve all pages.
    query.maxResults = 50;

    // We can specify the fields we want here to reduce the network
    // bandwidth and memory needed for the fetched collection.
    //
    // For example, leave query.fields as nil during development.
    // When ready to test and optimize your app, specify just the fields needed.
    // For example, this sample app might use
    //
    // query.fields = @"kind,etag,items(id,etag,kind,contentDetails)";

    _channelListTicket = [service executeQuery:query
                             completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                                                 GTLYouTubeChannelListResponse *channelList,
                                                 NSError *error) {
                                 // Callback

                                 // The contentDetails of the response has the playlists available for
                                 // "my channel".
                                 if ([[channelList items] count] > 0) {
                                     GTLYouTubeChannel *channel = channelList[0];
                                     _myPlaylists = channel.contentDetails.relatedPlaylists;
                                     NSLog(@"_myPlaylists: %@", _myPlaylists);
                                 }
                                 _channelListFetchError = error;
                                 _channelListTicket = nil;

                                 if (_myPlaylists) {
                                     [self fetchSelectedPlaylist];
                                 }

                                 [self fetchVideoCategories];
                             }];

}
```

After build and run, I sign in with my youtube account, when I click Agree in the page, the app crashes, here is the error output:

```
2013-09-30 04:12:47.618 YoutubeAPITest[4153:a0b] popView
2013-09-30 04:12:48.684 YoutubeAPITest[4153:a0b] fetchMyChannelList
2013-09-30 04:12:48.685 YoutubeAPITest[4153:a0b] GTLRuntimeCommon: unexpected attributes TB,D for property mine
2013-09-30 04:12:48.685 YoutubeAPITest[4153:a0b] GTLRuntimeCommon: unexpected return type class  for property "mine" of class "GTLQueryYouTube"
2013-09-30 04:12:48.686 YoutubeAPITest[4153:a0b] -[GTLQueryYouTube setMine:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1090c13e0
2013-09-30 04:12:48.689 YoutubeAPITest[4153:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[GTLQueryYouTube setMine:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1090c13e0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101a7c795 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001017df991 objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101b0dbad -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101a6e09d ___forwarding___ + 973
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101a6dc48 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   YoutubeAPITest                      0x0000000100001ae2 -[ViewController fetchMyChannelList] + 258
    6   YoutubeAPITest                      0x000000010000197a -[ViewController viewController:finishedWithAuth:error:] + 218
    7   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101a7222c __invoking___ + 140
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101a720d4 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 308
    9   YoutubeAPITest                      0x000000010001474d -[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch signIn:finishedWithAuth:error:] + 701
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101a7222c __invoking___ + 140
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101a720d4 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 308
    12  YoutubeAPITest                      0x00000001000113cf -[GTMOAuth2SignIn invokeFinalCallbackWithError:] + 415
    13  YoutubeAPITest                      0x000000010001121e -[GTMOAuth2SignIn finishSignInWithError:] + 62
    14  YoutubeAPITest                      0x0000000100010daa -[GTMOAuth2SignIn fetchGoogleUserInfo] + 506
    15  YoutubeAPITest                      0x000000010001096b -[GTMOAuth2SignIn auth:finishedWithFetcher:error:] + 251
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101a7222c __invoking___ + 140
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101a720d4 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 308
    18  YoutubeAPITest                      0x000000010000df43 +[GTMOAuth2Authentication invokeDelegate:selector:object:object:object:] + 355
    19  YoutubeAPITest                      0x000000010000c856 -[GTMOAuth2Authentication tokenFetcher:finishedWithData:error:] + 1334
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101a7222c __invoking___ + 140
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101a720d4 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 308
    22  YoutubeAPITest                      0x000000010001add8 -[GTMHTTPFetcher invokeFetchCallback:target:data:error:] + 344
    23  YoutubeAPITest                      0x000000010001ac4c -[GTMHTTPFetcher invokeFetchCallbacksWithData:error:] + 204
    24  YoutubeAPITest                      0x000000010001c165 -[GTMHTTPFetcher connectionDidFinishLoading:] + 1333
    25  Foundation                          0x00000001014d103b __65-[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:]_block_invoke + 48
    26  Foundation                          0x000000010138476b -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:] + 210
    27  Foundation                          0x000000010138467c -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withActiveConnectionAndDelegate:] + 69
    28  CFNetwork                           0x00000001068c88b7 ___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic26_delegate_didFinishLoadingEU13block_pointerFvvE_block_invoke + 107
    29  CFNetwork                           0x00000001068c6a82 ___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic18_withDelegateAsyncEPKcU13block_pointerFvP16_CFURLConnectionPK33CFURLConnectionClientCurrent_VMaxE_block_invoke_2 + 84
    30  CFNetwork                           0x000000010690a024 ___ZNK17CoreSchedulingSet13_performAsyncEPKcU13block_pointerFvvE_block_invoke + 25
    31  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101a230b4 CFArrayApplyFunction + 68
    32  CFNetwork                           0x0000000106839d7b _ZN19RunloopBlockContext7performEv + 115
    33  CFNetwork                           0x0000000106839bc1 _ZN17MultiplexerSource7performEv + 247
    34  CFNetwork                           0x00000001068399e4 _ZN17MultiplexerSource8_performEPv + 72
    35  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101a0be61 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    36  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101a0b732 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 242
    37  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101a275bf __CFRunLoopRun + 767
    38  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101a26ed3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    39  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000103b1d3a4 GSEventRunModal + 161
    40  UIKit                               0x0000000100447a63 UIApplicationMain + 1010
    41  YoutubeAPITest                      0x0000000100008c13 main + 115
    42  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001020ef7e1 start + 0
    43  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

It seems like the Authentication is succeed, but fetchMyChannelList failed: the error occur when setting value for mine propety of query. I have recheck all the steps but can't figure out what's wrong, please help.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into the same problem using the Google Calendar api.

GTLRuntimeCommon: unexpected attributes TB,D for property singleEvents

If your using the the Google-API-Client found on Cocoa Pods then this might be the cause. I found that the cocoapod is slightly outdated and crashes when setting booleans in queries on 64 bit iPhones. The source found here https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/ has been patched with a fix.

In case your curious here is the commit where it was patched https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/source/detail?r=364

Comment: I have created client ID and secret and when invoked search api, auth error 1001 is logging. Is it mandatory to login and fetch auth key for you tube search api?